# Do this implimentation of C3P0 in my web application is correct? What are the pros and cons of this implimentation?

Tags: java, servlets, connection-pooling, c3p0

I need to implement connection pooling my web application which uses Servlet and JSP pages. I don't want connection pooling across all application in server, want to implement connection pool across all servlets.

I have a working implementation of C3P0, But I don't know is this is the correct way to do it and do this gives expected result.

Following is my implementation
Have a Datasource file C3P0 implementation  to return the connection.
Connection will be retrieved on servelet init method and closed on destroy method.

- Do this type of implementation give expected result?
- Do i have to close the connection in destroy?
- What are other ways of   implementing connection pooling to servlet app?
- I like to move all db related actions to separate classes, in that case what are the things i have to take care of and do i have to get connection in servlet and pass to the db methods in that case too ?
- Please give the pros and  cons of the current implementation

Please find my connection pooling implementation below

Datasource file which returns a connection and Servelt which uses the connection

**Datasource file**

```
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource;


public class DataSource {

    // JDBC driver name and database URL
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://dburl/dbName";

    // Database credentials
    static final String USER = "username";
    static final String PASS = "password";  

    private static DataSource     datasource;
    private ComboPooledDataSource cpds;

    private DataSource() throws IOException, SQLException, PropertyVetoException {
        cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        cpds.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); //loads the jdbc driver

        cpds.setJdbcUrl(DB_URL);
        cpds.setUser(USER);
        cpds.setPassword(PASS);

        // the settings below are optional -- c3p0 can work with defaults
        cpds.setMinPoolSize(5);
        cpds.setAcquireIncrement(5);
        cpds.setMaxPoolSize(20);
        cpds.setMaxStatements(180);

    }

    public static DataSource getInstance() throws IOException, SQLException, PropertyVetoException {
        if (datasource == null) {
            datasource = new DataSource();
            return datasource;
        } else {
            return datasource;
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return this.cpds.getConnection();
    }

}
```

**Servlet**

```
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ConnectionTest
 */
@WebServlet("/ConnectionTest")
public class ConnectionTest extends HttpServlet {


Connection connection = null;
Statement statement = null;

@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {
    super.init();

    try {
        connection = DataSource.getInstance().getConnection();

    } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
 *      response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<h1> Hi</h1>");

    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    try {

        statement = connection.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement
                .executeQuery("SELECT VehicleRegistration  FROM Registration");
        while (resultSet.next()) {

            String first = resultSet.getString("VehicleRegistration");

            // Display values
            out.println("<h1> " + first + "</h1>");

        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (resultSet != null)
            try {
                resultSet.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        if (statement != null)
            try {
                statement.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
    if (connection != null) {
        try {

            connection.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    super.destroy();
}

}
```

I welcomes all suggestions even its too small or large which helps me to improve this code

Advance thanks to all

Comment: Why this negative vote, I like to improve the given code and its need expert advice and i think SO is for that "to improve the way we code"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this is could be improved.

Your Servlet should acquire a reference to the DataSource in `init(...)`, and not hold a Connection object outstanding for the life of the Servlet. `Connection` objects should be acquired from a Connection-pooling DataSource on an as-needed basis, not held open for long periods of time. Your `doGet(...)` method should acquire the Connection (which will be fast, because it will already be in the pool!), and then take care to call `close()` on the Connection in its finally block.

It's very important that you change this. Besides the ickiness and poor resource use of holding a Connection open forever, under your current architecture, simultaneous requests to your Servlet will operate concurrently on the same Connection, which can lead to unexpected and incorrect behavior, particular if there are servlets in your webapp that make use of transactions (as most nontrivial applications must).

Your DataSource class doesn't seem particularly useful. Why not just construct the c3p0 DataSource instead of defining a new kind of object with a `getConnection()` method. I think your motivation may have been just to have the static member `datasource` to be the one true DataSource. But if you want to store the DataSource as a static memberm you can do that anywhere, there's no need to wrap the actual DataSource.

The best place to hold a Connection-pool backed DataSource in a JavaEE web application is not as a static member, though. A much better approach is to construct your DataSource in a `ServletContextListener`, in `contextInitialized(...)`, and store the DataSource in the application scope. In `contextDestroyed(...)` call `close()` the c3p0 `ComboPooledDataSource`, and remove it from the application scope.

Comment: Thank you Steve, yeah I am sure this is a great improvement to what i already done.  Please review the modified files as per your suggestions

Datasource file
http://ctrlv.it/java/1811/4060924481

ServletContextListner
http://ctrlv.it/java/1812/1704021759

Servlet
http://ctrlv.it/java/1813/4206276490       

please have a look on them and is its right? I have modified the 'Datasource', Added new Servlet context listner and called the 'Datasource' contructer in 'contextInitialized()', passed it 'ComboPooledDataSource' as argument and used it in Servlet 'doGet()'

Comment: Hi Steve some more doubts, While using c3p0 do the connection.close() will close the connection or is it return connection to connection pool? If its close the connection then do the use of mysql stored procedures along with c3p0 in my servlet service methods give me the benefits of stored procedures. I found this "MySQL maintains its own stored procedure cache for every single connection. If an application uses a stored procedure multiple times in a single connection, the compiled version is used, otherwise the stored procedure works like a query."  and we closes it in each request

Comment: This is better. But I don't see the point of your DataSource class at all. You can set up your ComboPooledDataSource in the ServletContextListener directly. Why create a class whose constructor sets one up, only access it and throw away the wrapper object? It's needlessly indirect and confusing. Calling `connection.close()` on a Connection emitted by c3p0 PooledDataSource does not close() the physical Connection. The physical Connection gets checked into the pool and made available again.

Comment: Regarding the stored procedure cache, to get the most performance benefit that you can out of that, just don't expire Connections very quickly. By default, c3p0 doesn't expire Connections, but you should configure some Connection testing so that bad Connections get purged from the pool. Anyway, over use, the stored procedure cache of all pooled Connections will fill and you'll see increasing stored procedure performance, at least in theory.

Comment: Thank you Steve, thanks a lot for replying to my repeated comments , your answer and comments gives me great insights and improves me a lot...thank you man..